# Should I use Pylon's Paste to host my Pylons website? Or can I use Apache?

Tags: python, web-services, pylons

I'm looking into Pylons and was wondering, should I use Paste as the webserver or can I use Apache?

Are there advantages to using Paste?
Would you recommend against using Apache?

How should I host the sites?

Answer (score 2):

I guess it depends on whether you need webserver for development or production. For development just stick to Paste. I don't think there's one best way to host production application, but if you're not a pro in system administration, you can just go with Apache and mod_wsgi.

By the way, there's a great and comprehensive comparison of Python WSGI servers at http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers.

Comment: Except that the results in that comparison are flawed. The person who did it used a totally unrealistic Apache configuration. No person who knows how to configure Apache properly would configure it with 1000 threads per process, especially when hosting a Python web application. The result of their wrong choice for the configuration caused a significant bias against Apache, especially in memory usage. That set of benchmarks isn't the only flawed one out there. So, be very careful trusting benchmarks you find on peoples blogs, or even those quoted in Wikipedia for that matter.

Comment: @Graham Dumpleton thank you for information, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Nginx (with fastcgi) or Apache for hosting Pylons sites, mostly because lack of some "production" features in Paste, but for development Paste is very usefull and handy.